# Is it possible to make Regex replace non-greedy?

Tags: regex, powershell

```
"-dhello;-egoodbye;-lcul8r" -replace "-d.*;","-dbonjour;"
```

gives:

```
-dbonjour;-lcul8r
```

Is it possible to not have it get rid of `goodbye`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should make the matching lazy using `?`.

Use:

```
"-dhello;-egoodbye;-lcul8r" -replace "-d.*?;","-dbonjour;"
```

Answer (score 9):

Always be explicit. `.*` matches everything it can (including the semicolon and all that follows), but you only want to match until the *next* semicolon, so just tell the regex engine that:

```
"-dhello;-egoodbye;-lcul8r" -replace "-d[^;]*;","-dbonjour;"
```

`[^;]` matches any character *except*  semicolon.

Comment: Though this works in this case, it was just an example. I was really looking for a switch to turn off greediness. But, thanks, it's still useful advice.

Comment: @muhmud: Sure. I just wanted to express that ungreedy does not necessarily mean "the shortest possible match". You get that only when you specify exactly what the match contents may be. For example `<.*?>` will match `<baz <foo>` in `"<baz <foo> bam>"`.